# Sending JSON data with children objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to send a POST like this;

```
{
  "title": "sample string 2",
  "comment": "sample string 5",
  "child": {
    "name": "sample string 2"
  },
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "sample string"
        },
        {
            "name": "sample string"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am currently sending this

```
{
  "title": "sample string 2",
  "comment": "sample string 5"
}
```

using this
(in the controller)

```
vm.product = new Product();
vm.product.title = "My title";
vm.product.comment = "my comment";
```

with this resource factory

```
myApp.factory('Product', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://api.com/api/product/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

The above works. My questions is, how would i change the above code, so i can send child objects, as seen in the top?

I tried with

```
vm.product.child.name = "my new child"
```

But with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object with the information you want in it, then assign that:

```
var child = { "name" : "my new child" };
vm.product.child = child;
```

You can't assign directly to `var.product.child.name` because, at that point, there is no child to assign to - once you have assigned `vm.product.child`, you can add fields to it. In fact, this would also work:

```
vm.product.child = {};
vm.product.child.name = "my new child";
```

If you want an array of children:

```
vm.product.children = [];
var child = {"name":"my child name"};
vm.product.children.push(child);
```

Once you have set the value of `vm.product.children` to an array, you can push as many children as you want to it.

Comment: Ah yes, that works. So simple :)

But, how would i make the children, that is an array with objects?